# [Mapbox iOS SDK]: Polygon border fade-out / smooth border

Tags: swift, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-ios

If i use fil-in pattern in mapbox iOS sdk with a geojson file, the overlay gets a straight border or better so say sharp rectangular edges.
Is it possible to make those corners round and smooth out the border?
Maybe antialiasing? 
Even if i use a pattern that is round with transparency around it the border is still sharp and square.

See my example:

[image]

This is the code i use to display the polygon with overlay:

```
let polygon = Polygon(polygon)
            
    let polygonAnnotationManager: PolygonAnnotationManager
    
    polygonAnnotationManager = mapView.annotations.makePolygonAnnotationManager(id: managerID, layerPosition: nil)
    
    // Create the polygon annotation
    var polygonAnnotation = PolygonAnnotation(polygon: polygon)
            
    // Style the polygon annotation
    polygonAnnotation.fillPattern = imageName
    polygonAnnotationManager.fillAntialias = true
    
    // Add the polygon annotation to the manager
    polygonAnnotationManager.annotations = [polygonAnnotation]
```

Thank you in advance!
Best regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

As discussed with Mapbox on Git: Currently it's not possible.